# SCNFloor's firstMaterial's diffuse's content property as gradient

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, scenekit

I have this SCNFloor

```
SCNFloor *floor = [SCNFloor floor];
```

And I want to make a UIColor that is a gradient.

```
UIColor *myGradient = ?;
```

And I want to change this property to a gradient.

```
floor.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = myGradient;
```

Is there a way I can do this?

When I try to add an image

```
floor.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = @"myGradient";
```

It just gets repeated, which is an undesirable result.

When I try clamping the edged to the image

```
floor.firstMaterial.diffuse.wrapS = SCNWrapModeClamp;
floor.firstMaterial.diffuse.wrapT = SCNWrapModeClamp;
```

I get a solid color that's contained in the gradient.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: the fact that you are using a floor and want a gradient makes me think that `reflectionFalloffEnd` and `reflectionFalloffStart` are the properties you are looking for

Comment: I don't want a reflection. Right now the SCNFloor is a flat color. Let's say that color is green. I want to have a gradient that starts as a dark green as it's near the mainCamera. Then fades to a light green 1000 points away from the mainCamera.

Comment: have u found out a way to add a simple color to SCNFloor